# Why is the order of : and - important in a regexp character class

Tags: regular-expressions

Defining the following function

```
(defun windows-path-backwards ()
  (interactive)
  (skip-chars-backward "a-zA-Z0-9\\\\_-:"))
```

and running it while standing at | in the below text

```
C:\this\path|
```

moves it to

```
C:|\this\path
```

Redefining the function as

```
(defun windows-path-backwards ()
  (interactive)
  (skip-chars-backward "a-zA-Z0-9\\\\_:-"))
```

and repeating the same procedure moves the pointer from

```
C:\this\path|
```

to

```
|C:\this\path
```

Why is there difference between these two functions when the only change is the order of the `:` and `-` characters in the character class `skip-chars-backward` takes as an argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because `-` is used to denote ranges of characters. One will have to escape `-` for it to not have that meaning when placed between two other characters. See the function definition below:

```
(defun windows-path-backwards ()
  (interactive)
  (skip-chars-backward "a-zA-Z0-9\\\\_\\-:"))
```

In other words, `:` is not important in itself, it just happened to be one of two characters surrounding a `-` in the nonfunctioning example given in the question.

Comment: Although that's valid for `skip-chars-*`, because you can't *escape* `-` like that in a character alternative I'd be more inclined to use the techniques which are consistent between the two scenarios, so that it's less likely to seem like a mistake (as the two are documented as being mostly equivalent). "To include a ‘-’, write ‘-’ as the first or last character of the character alternative, or as the upper bound of a range."  Edge cases aside, I think backslash is the only character which always needs to be written differently for `skip-chars-*`.